# vlan line protocol up/down

Tags: vlan, cisco-3750

I have created L2 vlan & SVI's on core switch. but it shows status UP, Line protocol DOWN.

Vlan11                x.x.x.x      YES manual up                    down
Vlan21                x.x.x.x      YES manual up                    down
Vlan31                x.x.x.x      YES manual up                    down
Vlan91                x.x.x.x      YES manual up                    down

Comment: Do you have any interfaces assigned to the VLANs?

Comment: yes we have assigned 4 ports for that vlan.

Comment: And the interfaces assigned to those VLANs are UP/UP?

Comment: no, its showing Up/Down

Comment: You need the interfaces assigned to the VLANs to be UP/UP.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

In order for a VLAN interface to be up, the VLAN needs to be configured on a access port (Directly connected hosts) or the VLAN needs to be allowed over a trunk. Mind you that the interface or trunk need to be up for the VLAN interfaces to come up

You can configure access ports assigned to those VLAN's and use the command **no keepalive** command to bring those ports up, without having something actually connected to the physical port